# HP 8760w random crash error minidump

Tags: crash, bsod, hp-elitebook

I have a issue with my Elitebook 8760w that I just bought(Used), since I installed another 16GB of ram and a second hard drive I am having random crashes with this error code I have tested the ram with memtest and it was fine and the hard drive too here my error code, anyone faced this issue before?

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:    BlueScreen
  OS Version:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode:    9f
  BCP1:    0000000000000003
  BCP2:    FFFFFA8019491A10
  BCP3:    FFFFF80000B9C3D8
  BCP4:    FFFFFA801E92F010
  OS Version:    6_1_7601
  Service Pack:    1_0
  Product:    256_1

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Windows\Minidump\092114-18844-01.dmp
  C:\Users\Fred\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-102851-0.sysdata.xml

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
```

here the link to the .dmp file in my gdrive
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8rcOfF3iXjVVF82Y1hibTd5ZUE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If it is new, try a warranty claim? They sometimes fix it the next day at your house (US)

Comment: upload this file: C:\Windows\Minidump\092114-18844-01.dmp so that we can debug this crash

Comment: here:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8rcOfF3iXjVVF82Y1hibTd5ZUE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: does updating the driver fixes the issue?

Comment: so far so good thanks it as been running 2 days without crashing so I guess it's fix!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash seams to be caused by your Intel Wireless N6300 driver:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: fffffa8019491a10, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: fffff80000b9c3d8, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: fffffa801e92f010, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------


DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

IMAGE_NAME:  pci.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4ce7928f

MODULE_NAME: pci

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff88000f65000 pci

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
nt!KiProcessTimerDpcTable
nt!KiProcessExpiredTimerList
nt!KiTimerExpiration
nt!KiRetireDpcList
nt!KiIdleLoop


FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_Netwsw00_IMAGE_pci.sys

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_Netwsw00_IMAGE_pci.sys

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0x9f_3_power_down_netwsw00_image_pci.sys

!DevNode fffffa8019491740 :
  DeviceInst is "PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_422B&SUBSYS_11018086&REV_3E\247703FFFFE3B3A000"
  ServiceName is "NETwNs64"
```

So [Update the driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=24217&lang=eng) and it should be fixed.